# Why do my masonry.js items overlap each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, masonry

I am trying to use the popular [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/) library, but all the masonry items are overlapping each other, instead of being laid out masonry style.

I've read over the documentation quite a few times, and I'm sure the answer is in there somewhere, but I can't find it.

```js
jQuery('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

```css
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 40%;
}

.gutter-sizer {
  width: 4%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some Other here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    asdfasdff
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    214421342143
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it myself.

I forgot to add the `gutter-sizer` and `grid-sizer` html.

```js
jQuery('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

```css
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 40%;
}

.gutter-sizer {
  width: 4%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some Other here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    asdfasdff
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    214421342143
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Some text here
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```